# Disable Tapping Drag in xorg config on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, xorg.conf

I am using an Apple Magic Trackpad 2 on my Ubuntu (20.04) Laptop and it works really well. The only thing I want to change is disabling tapping drag. Currently I do this using `xinput set-prop`, but typing the commands after every reboot/logon is really tiresome and I would like to make the setting stick.

On https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml#heading9 and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/xorg.conf.5.html#inputclass%20section I found the description on the InputClass section of the configuration. A lot of options, but actually simple I guess. So I created this config block:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Apple Magic Trackpad" 
    MatchProduct "Magic Trackpad"
    Option "TappingDrag" "0"
EndSection
```

This should disable the `TappingDrag` option for all devices with "Magic Trackpad" in their name (hence "InputClass", a class of input devices).

The `TappingDrag` option I got from here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man4/libinput.4.html#configuration%20details. When running `xinput list-props <trackpad device id>` it shows as "libinput Tapping Drag Enabled", so I guess this setting is available for configuration.

Now I needed to figure out where to put this config and used this page: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/xorg.conf.5.html#description. It lists quite a lot of spaces where the configuration could live and I tried most of them with no effect. I also used different filenames: When a `xorg.conf.d` folder was used, I named the file like "10-apple.conf" because I think xorg compiles these files internally to build one configuration object or something.

To validate if it had worked, I logged off and on again and typed `xinput list-props <trackpad device id>` to see the value of "libinput Tapping Drag Enabled". Currently that value is always "1", but according to my config it should be "0".

- What do I need to do to make this setting persistent?
- Is there a way to look at the current xorg settings to check if the file has been loaded?
- Maybe there is an error in my config that I just haven't discovered?

I really appreciate any support on this!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set "TappingDrag" to "off" not 0.
Like this: Option "TappingDrag" "off"

Comment: please add the full command for it